# TouchWiz Air View no longer expanding / "exploding" home screen folders

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, home-screen, samsung-touchwiz, home-screen-folders

The TouchWiz [Air View](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000003/10147/120570) feature on my Samsung Galaxy S4 used to provide a very cool feedback feature where holding a finger over a home screen folder without actually touching it would cause the folder icon to expand / "explode" and show a clearer picture of everything that is in the folder before actually opening it.

This is no longer working, and I cannot figure out why.  (It is not critical by any means, but it is annoying me that I cannot figure it out.)  How can I and the other users impacted by this (below) fix this?

Since I can't get it working again, I can't post my own picture to better demonstrate what is expected - but the forum thread at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2730260 ("[Q] Air view for folders in GS4 I9505") describes my exact same issue and includes several screenshots - though it is also unsolved.

Another reference to the same issue also exists at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2601067&page=63 ("KitKat 4.4 thread", buried in 227 pages).

"Air view" and all of its options are ON under the "My device" settings, and working elsewhere as [advertised](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000003/10147/120570) in the other applications.  (I even tried turning it off and back on.)  It is only the home screen folders that are no longer working.  I've tried rebooting.  I even used the "Force stop", "Clear cache", and "Clear data" options from the Application Manager for "TouchWiz home" (Version 4.4.4-I337UCUFNJ4) - and while this caused everything else on the home screen to reset to defaults (requiring me to re-place all my icons and widgets), it did nothing to resolve the issue.

I have not applied any device / firmware updates since this stopped working - though I'm uncertain if anything came through Google Play automatic updates that would have caused this (I haven't installed new anything recently).  There was a "Samsung Galaxy" update on 2014-12-19, and a "Samsung account" update on 2014-12-29...

Stock AT&T firmware, Android 4.4.4, SGH-I337, Build Number KTU84P.I337UCUFNJ4.